# ORA-30175 on sys_extract_utc unified_audit_trail.event_timestamp in Oracle 12c R1

Tags: sql, oracle, audit-trail

I can run the following SQL on an Oracle 12c R2:

SQL:

```
select
sys_extract_utc(event_timestamp) as UTC_Time
from unified_audit_trail
```

But when the same in 12c R1, I get the following error:

ORA-30175 - invalid type given for an argument

When:

```
SQL>desc unified_audit_trail ;
```

in both 12c R1 and R2 there is:

```
EVENT_TIMESTAMP             TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE
```

the column data type is the same, so why is the error on 12c R1?